# Azure Logic app querying application insights returning code not html

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-logic-apps, azure-qna-maker

I have an Azure app that is supposed to query my qna maker bot and return a html table. instead it returns this. I'm following https://microsoft.github.io/slg-covid-bot/docs/telemetry-analytics.html

``` {"attachmentName":"azure_monitor_logs_flow_table_20200702195619.html","attachmentContent":"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","body":"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"} ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test in my side, I reproduced your problem. I query the logs in application insight and send it to my email (shown as below screenshot).

[image]

*In the screenshot above, I use the "Send an email(V2)" action in "Office 365 Outlook" connector but not "Outlook.com" connector.*

First we need to make sure the "**Chart Type**" in "Visualize Analytics query" should be selected as "**Html Table**". And then, when we put the "Body" into the "Send an email(V2)" action, we need to choose the correct "Body"(because there are two "Body" for us to choose).

[image]

Please choose second "Body" and put it into the "Send an email(V2)" action.

If choose the first "Body", you can click the `...` icon of the "Send an email(V2)" action, then click "Peek code". We can see it shows as below:

[image]

After running the logic app, we will receive the email as you provided.

If we choose second "Body", also open "Peek code", we can see it shows like this:

[image]

Run the logic app, it works fine and we will receive the email with html table in it.

**So please choose second "Body" and check the "Peek code" if you choose the correct "Body"**.

Comment: I was sure I had done that, but this time it did work! Thank you very much!